# Error: Invalid dest() folder argument. Please specify a non-empty string or a function

Tags: gulp, angular5, angular-universal

i cloned the repo ng-seed/universal 
then - npm install, 
then - npm run clean, then - npm run build:spa-dev (gives me error while) building

```
Finished 'bundle:spa-stage' after 1.42 min
[18:43:03] Starting 'copy:index.html'...
[18:43:03] 'copy:index.html' errored after 31 ms
[18:43:03] Error: Invalid dest() folder argument. Please specify a non-empty string or a function.
    at Gulp.dest (D:\xx\xx\universal\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\dest\index.js:21:11)
    at D:\xx\xx\universal\tools\build\gulp-helpers.js:56:36
    at D:\xx\xx\universal\node_modules\lazypipe\index.js:27:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at build (D:\xx\xx\universal\node_modules\lazypipe\index.js:26:37)
    at Object.exports.debug (D:\xx\xx\universal\tools\build\gulp-helpers.js:57:7)
    at copy (D:\xx\xx\universal\tools\build\gulp-tasks.js:90:18)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at asyncRunner (D:\xx\xx\universal\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Comment: Looks like its working fine for now.
i made a change in node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/dest/index.js
and commented the line 20-23
/*if (!outFolder) {
    throw new Error('Invalid dest() folder argument.' +
      ' Please specify a non-empty string or a function.');
  }*/

Comment: it was caused because of a misconfiguration at that repo, and it's fixed as of now. You can track the status at https://github.com/ng-seed/universal/issues/279

Answer (score 0):

With `console.log` I output the variables that were used for DEST and found out **that some were not yet set**. *Maybe that will help one or the other.*

```
gulp.task(function minify_html() {

  var SRC = variables.config.sourceHTML;

  return (gulp
    .src(SRC)
    
   (...)

    .pipe(gulp.dest(variables.config.targetHTML))
    .pipe(gulpif(variables.settings.isServer, browser_sync.stream())));

console.log(variables.config.targetHTML); // 


});
```

For the sake of completeness, I use `let variables = require ('./ variables.json')` to maintain the settings separately